# How to refresh AT-SPI registry in pyatspi

Tags: python, gnome

I am trying to read Chrome URL value with the pyatspi, but the problem is when I start the Chrome, the pyatspi throws an error (`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'getChildAtIndex'`). Code which I am using for fetching the URL:

```
import pyatspi
reg = pyatspi.Registry()
desktop = reg.getDesktop(0)
c1 = pyatspi.findDescendant(desktop, lambda x: x.name == "Google Chrome", breadth_first=True)
c2 = c1.getChildAtIndex(0)
c3 = c2.getChildAtIndex(1)
c4 = c3.getChildAtIndex(0)
c5 = c4.getChildAtIndex(1)
c6 = c5.getChildAtIndex(4)
c7 = c6.getChildAtIndex(3)
url = c7.get_text(0, -1)
```

The error which is raised is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<path_to_file>", line 7, in <module>
    c4 = c3.getChildAtIndex(0)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'getChildAtIndex'
```

When I use [Accerciser](https://help.gnome.org/users/accerciser/stable/introduction.html.en) and refresh AT-SPI registry by clicking inside the app, I do not have any problems with fetching the URL. I assume this is due to caching (mentioned in this [mail](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/gnome-accessibility-devel/2011-May/msg00028.html)) of AT-SPI registry, but I am wondering if there is any way to force the refresh of registry in pyatspi?

Comment: Can it be achieved with `atspi` branch of [pywinauto](https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto) ? `pip install https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/archive/refs/heads/atspi.zip` This library uses `libatspi.so` directly, but it's not fully release ready. Current PyPI release doesn't contain ATSPI code.